# How to insert normal text right below a block of text in Windows?

Tags: windows, microsoft-word, styles, evernote

In programs such as Microsoft Word, Wordpad or even Evernote, it is possible to insert tables, lists or code block. If that block appear on the last line of the document, how to insert a normal text below it?

Here a document with a table in Microsoft Word, where the table is the last item on the document. If try to place my cursor at the furthermost possible place, I will end right after `B`. If I press enter, I may just insert a new row but I won't escape the table.

```
.------.------.
|  A   |   B  |
'------'------'
```

What I want to know, is how I can insert normal text right after the table like this:

```
.------.------.
|  A   |   B  |
'------'------'    
Normal text here...
```

What I usually do is:

```
1. Select the whole table
2. Cut
3. Insert plenty of new lines
4. Paste my table above empty lines
5. Click on one empty line below the table
6. Insert my normal text.
```

I also encounter this issue with Evernote.

Comment: The issue might occur in a variety of apps, but the solution may be specific to each program, there may not be a one-size-fits-all answer.  That will make it hard (or excessively broad), to answer your question.  It will be easier to answer, and to verify what works and what doesn't, if you limit this question to a single package.  If you get a solution for that package, but it doesn't work in another package, post a new question for that package.

Answer (score 4):

In Microsoft Word:

Click somewhere in the last row of the table and press the right arrow on your keyboard until the cursor moves outside the table:

[image]

Now, instead of pressing `Enter`, hold the `Shift` key and press `Enter`. This will create a line break below the table instead of a new table row.

Comment: It does not really work

Comment: It does work in MS Word. I've edited the original answer given by @WilliamAllen to include a screenshot. Please try again.

Comment: @Atzmon - Thanks. By the way - you should be able to just press the right arrow again instead of using shift and enter. The same behaviour also exists in Evernote and Outlook.

Comment: @WilliamAllen Yes, you can do that in Word (Outlook uses Word as its editor so it's the same). That's because there's always a paragraph at the end so the next right arrow press brings the cursor to that paragraph. If you change Word options to display paragraph marks you'll notice it (see this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hzvLu.png) ). I've also corrected my previous edit to your answer, to mention that `SHIFT`+`ENTER` actually inserts a line break, not a paragraph. I don't know much about Evernote though.

Answer (score 0):

Simply press the right arrow key (or even the down arrow key) when your cursor is at the end of the table. Your cursor will move down to a new line where you can enter text outside of the table.